# Is the Braces in the following statement means an open array?

Tags: java

```
Integer[] ints = list.toArray(new Integer[]{});
```

If I remove "`{}`" the compiler asks to fill in a dimension for the array. What do the two braces mean as a command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you initialize the array with what is in between the braces. Ex:

```
new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3}
```

Makes an array with 1, 2 and 3. On the other hand:

```
new Integer[] {}
```

Just mean that you initialize an array without any values. So it is the same as `new Integer[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

This actually means empty array. The `{}` allow you to supply the elements of the array:

```
Integer[] ints = list.toArray(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
```

is equivalent to:

```
Integer[] ints = new Integer[3];
ints[0] = 1;
ints[1] = 2;
ints[2] = 3;
```

Check this link:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

for more information - go to `Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array` section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an empty array. Just like Integer[0].